# My friends can't view posts published via my Open Graph application although I am able to

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I have been trying to integrate [Open Graph](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) into my website. It is basically a wordpress blog. Each post is considered an article.

I created an Open Graph app, and used Open Graph API so it will post read actions (news.reads) whenever user reads an article. This has been done thanks to the instructions provided in Facebook's great tutorials.

I also added a log in button which asks for the following permissions: publish_actions, read_stream, publish_stream.

### First issue I am having

When I used my own account, as the developer, everything worked just fine. The read actions were successfully posted on my Timeline.
However, when I used a different Facebook account (my brother's), the actions weren't posted at all. I allowed the same permissions with both accounts (publish_actions, read_stream, publish_stream), so why did it work on my account but didn't work on my brother's?

### Second issue I am having

Another strange behavior I have found, is that when viewing my own timeline using my brother's account, I am not able to see the read actions that were published earlier. When viewing the same timeline from my real account, these read actions exist. This is very strange because **they are all set to be public posts.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This simply means your [opengraph](/questions/tagged/opengraph) action is not approved. while your action is not approved, it will work only for admin, developer and auth dialog preview user. so solution is to submit your action for approval and when it gets approved it will work for all users and also your posts will be visible to all of them.

Comment: @IdoDoron hey if the answer helped then you should accept or upvote it.